# How to call farbtastic (color picker)

Tags: php, jquery

I use the farbtastic color picker, I included all files for this, but how can I call this color picker when I double click?

#### More info:

That's my placeholder in my .tpl file. and I call it as follow.

```
// color picker selecteren.
$(function(){
    $("#color").dbclick(function(){
        $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
    });
});

<!-- new color form -->
<form action="controller.php" method="post" class="popupform" id="form_changecolor">
    <div id="colorpicker"></div>
    <table>
    <tr><th>huidige:</th><th>nieuwe:</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="oldcolor" disabled="disabled" id="oldcolor" /></td><td><input type="text" name="newcolor" id="newcolor" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonrow">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{$PAGE}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="changecolor" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="parameter_key" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="btnOk" value="Aanpassen" />
    <input type="button" class="btnCancel" value="Annuleren" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

@NeXXeus, I already try it to do so (too big for a comment, and useful in the context of this question):

That's my placeholder in my .tpl file. and I call it as follow.

```
// color picker selecteren.
$(function(){
    $("#color").dbclick(function(){
        $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
    });
});

<!-- new color form -->
<form action="controller.php" method="post" class="popupform" id="form_changecolor">
    <div id="colorpicker"></div>
    <table>
    <tr><th>huidige:</th><th>nieuwe:</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="oldcolor" disabled="disabled" id="oldcolor" /></td><td><input type="text" name="newcolor" id="newcolor" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="buttonrow">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{$PAGE}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="module" value="changecolor" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="parameter_key" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="btnOk" value="Aanpassen" />
    <input type="button" class="btnCancel" value="Annuleren" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Double click what, where? Have you got the color picker working without double-clicking?

Comment: The question is, 'How' can I call the color picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question isn't very clear, this page has a very nice description on setting it up: http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic

Basing off of the example there, if you only want it to become a colorpicker when it is double-clicked...

```
$("#color").dblclick(function(){
    $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
});
```