# call farbtastic color picker with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

## update

I just try to call the farbtastic color picker, all scripts are included in the Html. the following code is a form with the color picker as placeholder. How can I call my farbtastic color picker? I'm using the following javascript code enclosed.

```
enter code here <form action="controller.php" method="post" class="popupform" id="form_changecolor">

<div id="colorpicker"></div>

<table>
  <tr><th>huidige:</th><th>nieuwe:</th></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="oldcolor" disabled="disabled" id="oldcolor" />
  </td><td><input type="text" name="newcolor" id="newcolor" /></td></tr>
</table>
<div class="buttonrow">
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="{$PAGE}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="module" value="changecolor" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="parameter_key" value="" />
  <input type="submit" class="btnOk" value="Aanpassen" />
  <input type="button" class="btnCancel" value="Annuleren" />
</div>
```

```
enter code here // color picker.
$("#content").dblclick(function() {
    alert('color picker');
    $("#colorpicker").farbtastic("#color");
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call farbtastic (color picker).](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443728/how-to-call-farbtastic-color-picker)

Answer (score 2):

See [Basic Usage on the plugin's site](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the empty div in place in your code. And place the jQuery script first before the farbtastic script

```
<form>
   <label for="color">Color:</label>
   <input id="color" type="text" value="#123456" />
   <div id="colorpicker"></div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $("#colorpicker").farbtastic("#color");
  });
</script>
```